# I can't upgrade from Ubuntu11.10 to 12.04

Tags: upgrade

when I try to upgrade the system ,it always failed.

```
W:无法下载 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:无法下载 gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/cn.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_i18n_Translation-en  Encountered a section with no Package: header
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading using a Live CD or USB.  You can use unetbootin [UnetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to install it on a USB.  It's usually a good idea to do a clean install when upgrading.

Comment: if i do a clean install, will i get my files lost?

Comment: Yes so you will need to back up your files either in the cloud, USB drive, external hard drive, or a CD/DVD.